# datagridview update row to csv file

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I am working with Csv file and datagridview in a C# project for a inventory app, I try to update a row to CSV file!

i need to update if user edit a row **current word** with a **new word** but my problem here is i need save the current word and new word and get total in pseudo code example:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if(row in column is modified)
                    update specific row with comma to current file and load it...
            }
```

Csv file is look like,
Current:

> **1;2;;4;5**

Update:

> **1;2,A;;4;5** changed device **A** total: 1 time...

Next row modified :

> **1;A;;4**,**B**,**C;5** changed device **B** and **C** total change : 2 time...

With a database it's easy to update data but i don't have sql server installed so this option has not for me i think..

My goal is for tracking device out/in so if you have a solution please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using an SQL server, maybe something [like this could help](http://www.litedb.org/)? [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/) You'd have your LiteDB to host your data, and export it CSV whenever you need. Working with CSV files usually means you'll re-write the whole file every time there is an update to make... Which is slow and cumbersome. I recommend you use CSV to transport data from Point A to Point B, but not to maintain data.

Also, if you really want to stick to CSV, have a look at the Microsoft Ace OLEDB driver, previously known as JET driver. I use it to query CSV files, but I have never used it to update... so your mileage may vary.

Short of using an actual DataBase or a database driver, you'll have to use a StreamReader along with a StreamWriter. Read the file with the StreamReader, write the new file with the StreamWriter. In your StreanReader. This implies you'll have code in your StreamReader to find the correct Line(s) to update.

Here's the class I created and am using to interact with LiteDB. It's not all that robust, but it did exactly what I needed it to do at the time. I had to make changes to a slew of products hosted on my platform, and I used this to keep track of the progress.

```
using System;
using LiteDB;

namespace FixProductsProperty
{

    public enum ListAction
    {
        Add = 0,
        Remove,
        Update,
        Disable,
        Enable
    }

    class DbInteractions
    {
        public static readonly string dbFilename = "MyDatabaseName.db";
        public static readonly string dbItemsTableName = "MyTableName";
        public void ToDataBase(ListAction incomingAction, TrackingDbEntry dbEntry = null)
        {

            if (dbEntry == null)
            {
                Exception ex = new Exception("dbEntry can not be null");
                throw ex;
            }


            // Open database (or create if not exits)
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(dbFilename))
            {

                var backupListInDB = db.GetCollection<TrackingDbEntry>(dbItemsTableName);

                //ovverride action if needed
                if (incomingAction == ListAction.Add)
                {
                    var tempone = backupListInDB.FindOne(p => p.ProductID == dbEntry.ProductID);
                    if (backupListInDB.FindOne(p => p.ProductID == dbEntry.ProductID) != null)
                    {
                        //the record already exists
                        incomingAction = ListAction.Update;
                        //IOException ex = new IOException("Err: Duplicate. " + dbEntry.ProductID + " is already in the database.");
                        //throw ex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //the record does not already exist
                        incomingAction = ListAction.Add;
                    }
                }

                switch (incomingAction)
                {
                    case ListAction.Add:
                        backupListInDB.Insert(dbEntry);
                        break;
                    case ListAction.Remove:
                        //backupListInDB.Delete(p => p.FileOrFolderPath == backupItem.FileOrFolderPath);
                        if (dbEntry.ProductID != 0)
                        {
                            backupListInDB.Delete(dbEntry.ProductID);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ListAction.Update:
                        if (dbEntry.ProductID != 0)
                        {
                            backupListInDB.Update(dbEntry.ProductID, dbEntry);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ListAction.Disable:
                        break;
                    case ListAction.Enable:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                backupListInDB.EnsureIndex(p => p.ProductID);
                // Use Linq to query documents
                //var results = backupListInDB.Find(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Jo"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
DbInteractions yeah = new DbInteractions();
yeah.ToDataBase(ListAction.Add, new TrackingDbEntry { ProductID = dataBoundItem.ProductID, StoreID = dataBoundItem.StoreID, ChangeStatus = true });
```

Sorry... my variable naming convention sometimes blows...

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'll check docs, have you used litedb before? if you have a example i will be happy to implement LiteDB to my app require 1 dll for working it's prefect..

Comment: I have used LiteDB before and it was quite nice for my `low tech` requirements. The front page of [their website](http://www.litedb.org/) has code samples near the bottom. That's where I started.

Comment: @Kate, updated my post with a copy/paste of my LiteDB class.

Comment: thank you for your example, i will check and test to implement to my project right now...